# SP2010: Autofill from Person or Group column

Tags: 2010, list

Using Sharepoint Designer 2010 and no access to Foundation, VB, or installation of third-party software, is it possible to do the following:

1. I have a People or Group column called Student Name. It allows the users to search our AD database and captures the name.
2. I would like a second column next to it, called Student Email, that auto fills the email associated with the person in Student Name.

Unfortunately, I don't have access to making customized code, but might be able to inject Javascript with a little help.

Is there any way to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [SPJS Utility](http://spjsblog.com/2013/08/20/spjs-utility-js-v1-17/) and [SPJS Autocomplete](http://spjsblog.com/2014/03/29/autocomplete-for-text-and-people-picker-fields/) libraries, I was able to implement this dynamically with the following code:

```
//intialize fields
fields = init_fields_v2();

//Autocomplete email column from name column
spjs.ac.peoplePicker({
"applyTo":"Student_x0020_Name",
"forceOn2013":false,
"helpText":"Enter name or email address...",
"showField":"Title",
"chooseFromUserGroup":null,
"showUsersOnly":true,
"rowLimit":5,
"listOptionsOnFocus":false,
"reValidateOnLoad":false,
"setFields":[
    {
        "fromFIN":"EMail",
        "toFIN":"Student_x0020_Email",
        "skipIfEmpty":false
    }
]
});
```

Comment: Nice to hear you completed the task! Cheers!!!

Comment: Thank you! My knowledge of Javascript is limited so I appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage `SPServices` http://spservices.codeplex.com/. Download the js library file and upload it into a SharePoint library (ex Site Assets)

Then edit the page in question, add a content editor webpart and link the JS files.

Now handle the `onchange` event of the text box where the search is happening, then use `SPServices` http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=GetUserProfileByName method to get additional information of the selected user.

And populate the email of the selected user.

Comment: Does this work for normal lists? I'm just looking to edit a list, not a separate page.

Comment: Yes you can edit the list (new/edit form) page and add a script editor webpart. You can use browser developer tools to find out the html tag id's for hooking up the events.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain the Javascript in your answer a bit more? I'm still a beginner at Javascript unfortunately.

Comment: Ok. The SharePoint page you are talking about is rendered as HTML objects. The people control is a text box where users can type. So using JavaScript add a keydown event handler and capture the data. In the same handler using the value in the textbox, invoke a SPServices call to getuserprofilebyname. This will return you the details of the selected user in XML format. You can use that to find the Email and populate another element (ex a textbox)

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. I may be grabbing the wrong code but I don't believe this is working. Do you mind looking over [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/kLamegbv/)?

Comment: Is there any JavaScript error? You can debug the request and response to find what is happening over the wire.

Comment: No errors in the console. I don't believe I'm getting the right IDs. When it comes to People or Group fields, I have grabbed the ID from the textarea field and not the div before it. I'm not sure if that's right though.

Comment: You can add alert statements and debug what values are getting captured from the key events. The idea is to get the person profile name and pass it to the webservice method. If the profile name is stored in a div you can read from that instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20214/discussion-between-nicolefdesigns-and-amal-hashim).

Comment: Take a look at this http://spjsblog.com/2010/05/28/get-or-set-value-for-sharepoint-field-in-newform-editform-and-dispform-get-only-in-dispform/ and use that library for pulling information from Person field.